# Nginx custom error_page always tries to load static file first

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx config:

```
location /json-error/404 {
  default_type application/json;
  try_files /errors/404.json =404;
  internal;
}

location ~ '^/api/' {
  default_type application/json;

  error_page 404 /json-error/404;

  # All my other location blocks go here  
}
```

If I visit `/api/unknown-route` it *does* load my custom 404 page, but in the nginx/error.log I also see

> open() ".../nginx/../static/api/unknown-route" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/unknown-route HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Why is this trying to open the static page? I don't want to see these errors in my Nginx log file

Comment: To stop Nginx logging 404 responses to the error log, try `log_not_found off;` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#log_not_found).

Comment: @RichardSmith that's just turning the logging on/off. I still want to know why Nginx tries to first load the `root` before loading the custom error page. Also, I have other 4xx error pages too. Those would still be logged then.

Comment: It’s difficult to tell from the small part of the configuration in your question. Generally, Nginx has to try to open a file to know it doesn’t exist in order to trigger the 404 status response.

Comment: I see, you mean it first tries to load my existing `location` directives, then it falls back to `root` and tries to load the page as a static asset, and if that's not found, then it renders the `error_page`? That actually makes sense, not sure why I forgot about that.